# Setting font-family in brackets IDE

Tags: css, adobe-brackets, font-family

I just started using Brackets, an IDE that I really love. However, I have encountered a problem with the "font-family". It only has six fonts— cursive, inherit, sans-serif, serif and monospace. So please, how can I go about it to have more useful fonts in the IDE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fonts are not related to your IDE. In your css the font family lets you pick the font you want and fallbacks in case the first font is not installed. Either you can use generic fonts that are installed by default on OS or you can link them in your html file using Google font for example.

Here is some documentation about it

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-family